# Regular Expression - Text field must begin with xx/xx date format

Tags: regex, salesforce, formula

I'm new to regex. I need to ensure that a text field begins with a date format of `xx/xx`, e.g. `03/15` for `March 15th`. After the date, any combination of characters is allowed. Here is what I've come up with so far for the regex portion:

```
^[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{2}
```

This ensures the text field begins with a date format of `xx/xx` but Users are not able to enter any additional characters after the date as they should. Thoughts? The text field has a character limit of 255 overall so I'm assuming I need to account for the other 250 potential characters in some way?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: If the regex validation is applied to the whole string, add `.*` at the end, `^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}.*`

Comment: thanks! worked great. i wanted to ensure a space character is present after the digits, so i updated the regex to: 
^[0-9]{2}[/][0-9]{2}[\s].*
but i'm getting a syntax error. why doesn't [\s] account for the space character after the digits?

Comment: You are probably using POSIX regex. Then, either use a regular space or `[[:space:]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} .*
```

It will match

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{2}` - two digits
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[0-9]{2}` - two digits
- - a space
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible.